# How do I decrease the display brightness an Acer 5830TG?

Tags: laptop, display, brightness

I am facing a problem with display brightness in Ubuntu or other versions of Linux. Running a Linux distro as live or HDD installation or inside the installation, display brightness is automatically set to the highest value, I'm unable to decrease it, this is an annoying problem at night.

I have tried about 25 different Linux Distros in my laptop another 3 laptops of friends but the same problem, no problem with the desktop as the monitor has its own brightness control switch.

> My laptop is Acer 5830TG, i5 2410M @ 2.3 GHz, ram-3gb, HDD-640gb @5400 rpm, NVIDIA GT540M,
>   chipset-Intel HM65. OEM os- windows7 Home Premium.

I have tried the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd> (left arrow key) as in windows, Ubuntu is showing that brightness is decreased but not really, display brightness is same.
Also tried Ubuntu display brightness applet.

And at Terminal`~$ sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=**` where `**` is two digit hex value, 00:02.0 is internal display adapters(Intel HD 3000) hardware address(lspci | grep VGA).

Nothing happened, display brightness remained the same.

Answer (score 4):

Try below,

execute `gksu gedit /etc/default/grub`

Change this line

`GRUB_CMLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

to something like below

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"`

Execute `sudo update-grub` and reboot . See if brightness keys are working.

It is still possible ubuntu won't remember your brightness settings. So you have to change brightness each time.

---

This is for setting brightness manually after doing the above steps.

Try following for paths shown by `ls /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness` and replace accordingly.

example paths will be like

```
/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

1. For the above path Get the maximum brightness:

`cat  /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness`

Try a lower value to set the brightness, say output is 16 so I will try with half of it

`echo 8 | sudo tee  /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`

**If this works**,  make this happen in each login automatically by doing the following

`sudo gedit /etc/rc.local`

Enter this line just before `exit 0`. It should look like

```
echo YOUR_VALUE_HERE > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo touch /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

insert next text:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier "card0"
   Driver "intel"
   Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"
   BusID "PCI:0:2:0"

EndSection
```

save, and reboot.
After reboot <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>arrow</kbd> key should work

Comment: I was using this trick in 13.10 and 14.04. I don't need it anymore in 14.10 with intel hd 4000