# Brightness control not working on HP omen AMD version

Tags: brightness, amd-processor

I have recently bought a HP Omen series laptop with AMD processor. I have installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on it. I am not able to adjust brightness. Initially I couldn't see the brightness controller either but after certain configurations I am able to see it now. But, still the brightness can't seem to change. I have tried all the possible solutions provided in other answers but nothing seems to work in my case.

Comment: It's Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. I have updated the description too.

Comment: I have found the solution in the below link. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1249152/ubuntu-20-04-lenovo-ideapad-5-ryzen-4800u-display-brightness-not-working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 Lenovo IdeaPad 5 Ryzen 4800u Display Brightness not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1249152/ubuntu-20-04-lenovo-ideapad-5-ryzen-4800u-display-brightness-not-working)